# Django-CMS warning on django-mptt

Tags: django, django-cms, django-mptt

I have a Django-CMS 2.4.1 project that always gives me the warning:

```
DeprecationWarning: Implicit manager CMSPlugin.tree will be removed in django-mptt 0.6.  Explicitly define a TreeManager() on your model to remove this warning.
```

This only occurs in production - not in dev.

I tried:

```
./manage.py cms fix-mptt
```

which gives me the output (after the same warning as above):

```
fixing mptt page tree
fixing mptt plugin tree
all done
```

But... this does not solve the problem, e.g. if I repeat the command it does the same thing again, with the same warning.

The warning doesn't seem to be doing any harm yet, but I imagine it will with the next version of django-mptt.  Can anyone give me any advice?

thanks

Comment: It sounds like you have different versions of MPTT between development/production

Comment: True, but they are both version 0.5.2.  I just upgraded them both to 0.5.5, and I am happy to report the warning message is now gone.  So I'm not sure what the problem was, but it seems to be fixed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can safely ignore that warning in any case.

It's just telling you that django CMS's use of Django MPTT is relying on something that will be removed in a future version.

Comment: OK, thanks.  Do you know if upgrading to mptt 0.5.5 is going to cause problems somewhere else?

Comment: If it is, you will find out soon enough. Do however check the docs for whatever version of django CMS you're using, and make sure that your version of MPTT is compatible. There were some changes in one version of MPTT (that were later rectified) that were not compatible.

Comment: @RacingTadpole As long as you use django CMS 2.4.x you won't be able to upgrade any further than v0.5.2. This is specified as a dependency in django-cms 2.4.x: `django-mptt>=0.5.1,<0.5.3` (see [setup.py](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/2.4.3/setup.py)).

Answer (score 5):

Harmless but utterly annoying, make the b*tch shut up:

```
CMSPlugin.tree = CMSPlugin.objects
```

in any module of early execution (models.py for example).

Comment: Didn't work for me. Is there a specific order of the installed apps where this hack should be placed?