# Django-CMS 2.4 pages with SITE_ID 2 only found if you're logged in

Tags: django, django-cms, django-sites

I have two sites using Django-CMS.  They use the same code and the same database, with the `SITE_ID` distinguishing them.

On the site with `SITE_ID = 1`, all is fine.

On the site with `SITE_ID = 2`, some pages that I publish (using the admin panel) can only be seen on the site if you are logged in. Otherwise they give me a 404 Error with a message like

```
CMS: Page not found for "test"
```

Other pages are ok - specifically the home page, and pages with apphooks.

If I set `DEBUG = False`, I get 404 errors on all my site's pages!

This is happening both in prod and on my dev server.  In fact it happens even on a completely vanilla test site that I have just created too.

I did not chose "login required" for any of the pages.

How can I make the pages visible to all?

Version info: I am using Django-CMS 2.4.1 and Django 1.5.1.  I also upgraded them to mptt 0.5.5, although Django-CMS specifically only installs mptt 0.5.2 (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682693/django-cms-warning-on-django-mptt) for why).  However, when I re-installed mptt 0.5.2 on my dev server the problem remained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I raised this as an [issue](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/1881) and now have the answer - it is the `'public': False` line in this code:

```
CMS_LANGUAGES = {
    1: [
        {
            'code': 'en',
            'name': gettext('English'),
            'public': True,
        },
    ],
    'default': {
        'fallbacks': ['en',],
        'public': False,
        }
}
```

The key "1" is the `SITE_ID`, so the above says to hide all sites after number 1 from the public.

So the solution is to add an entry keyed off `SITE_ID` 2 in the `CMS_LANGUAGES` setting.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to first have a look at the ALLOWED_HOSTS setting (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts).  This is very likely the reason you get errors when you turn off DEBUG. (although, I thought not having a legit ALLOWED_HOSTS would produce 500 errors, not 404s.).

Comment: Thanks - yes, I have `ALLOWED_HOSTS` set. I'm pretty sure it's right as I can see site 1 fine at the same location. I've raised a ticket at https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/1881.